# Cannot get 'deepLink.getQueryParameter("...")' from shared firebase dynamic link

Tags: android, firebase-dynamic-links

I am developing dynamic link to share a page content to open it directly in the same application from another device.
When I create an share a dynamic link, I am adding query parameter 'hotelId',
but when I click the shared link and try to open the link, application is opening normally, but deepLink.getQueryParameter("hotelId") always return null.
Here is my code:

Genarate dynamic link (DetailActivity)

```
onCreate(){
...

   DynamicLink dynamicLink = 
   FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse("www.example.com"))
            .setDynamicLinkDomain("example.page.link/hotelDetail?hotelId="+hotelId)
            // Open links with this app on Android
            .setAndroidParameters(new 
    DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build())
            // Open links with com.example.ios on iOS
            .setIosParameters(new 
    DynamicLink.IosParameters.Builder("com.example.exampleDark").build())
            .buildDynamicLink();

    Uri dynamicLinkUri = dynamicLink.getUri();
    Log.e("DynamicLink -",dynamicLinkUri.toString());

   //Share Dynamic Link
   try {
        URL url = new URL(URLDecoder.decode(myDynamicLink.toString(), "UTF-8"));
        Log.i("Share Link", "URL = :"+url.toString());

        // [START ddl_share_link]
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Firebase Deep Link");
        //String msg = "Hey, check this out: \n" + link;
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url.toString());

        startActivity(sendIntent);
        // [END ddl_share_link]

        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           Log.i(TAG, "Could not decode Uri: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
 ...
 }
```

Update manifest.xml to receive dynamic link

```
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- [START link_intent_filter] -->

        <!-- handle website links -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:host="example.page.link" android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:host="example.page.link" android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- [END link_intent_filter] -->
    </activity>
```

To get Dynamic link from shared URL (DetailActivity)

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new 
    OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                    Uri deepLink = null;
                    if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                        deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                        String path = deepLink.getPath();

                        //if(path.equals("/hotelDetail")){
                        String hId = deepLink.getQueryParameter("hotelId");

                        Log.i("Get Parameters", " Hotel = :" + hId + " Offer = :");

                    } else {
                        Log.i("Get Parameters", "No Hotel Link");
                    }

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.i("Get Parameters", "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                }
            });
```

Values defined on my Firebase console

```
URL Link - https://example.page.link/hotelDetail
Dynamic Link - https://example.page.link/hotelDetail?hotelId
```

After I shared a content, I am getting below link as dynamic link (Shared link)

```
 https://example.page.link/hotelDetail?hotelId=6q7a99a78d7fb63f330g2w6d?apn=myapp.com.myapp&ibi=com.example.exampleDark&link=www.example.com
```

What I want is, When I click shared link, I want to get the 'hotelId' value to the DetailActivity from the shared link.

Please can anyone help me what I am missing? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you get answer i have facing same issue!

Comment: have you found a solution ? I'm encountering the same problem. I tried @Limmonica's answer , but it's not working

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late answer. Got the same problem, so I leave this for others.

You should get the query parameter from the Intent

```
intent.getData().getQueryParameter(hotelId);
```

The

```
deepLink.getQueryParameter("hotelId");
```

will always be *null* because

```
pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
```

will return only your short dynamic link namely

```
https://example.page.link/hotelDetail
```

Comment: I am still facing the issue. Not getting the query param in intent. I am creating the dynamic link from firebase console and appending a query param manually before receiving it

Comment: Can you give me more details, perhaps code? From what I see above, there is also an issue related to app link mapping [https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing?utm_source=android-studio#associatesite]. Moreover, whatever link you use, you have to whitelist it in Firebase Authentication > Templates.

Comment: I got the issue. Basically there are two links. The dynamic firebase link and the deep link inside it. If we add the query param to the dynamic link then we will get in intent, if we add the param to deep-link, we will get it inside the deep link (deepLink.getQueryParameter("hotelId")). Also, a proper base URL has to be mentioned as a host in Manifest to get it via the intent. I had missed that.